# DOM style change waiting for pause

Tags: javascript, html

When this function is called, the style change on the "gif" element does not show up until "lotsOfProcessing()" finishes. However, when I uncomment the alert("test"), the style change is shown before the alert pops up.

What I am trying to do is have an animated gif displayed while lotsOfProcessing is running. This seemed pretty straight forward solution but it is clearly not working. Any suggestions / solutions?

```
function nameOfFuntion()
    {
        document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";
        //alert("test");
        lotsOfProcessing();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript code executes on the same thread as the browser's rendering.  **Everything** that needs to be drawn waits for JavaScript execution to complete - including the next frame of any GIF animation.

The only solution is to break your long processing code down into smaller parts and delay each part using timers.

For example:

```
function nameOfFuntion() {
    document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";
    //alert("test");
    lotsOfProcessing();
}

function lotsOfProcessing() {
    var i = 0;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        partOfIntenseProcessing();
        if (i < 1000000)
            i++, window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

This will delay how long it will take for your processing to complete, but between timer execution the GIF can continue to animate.

You can also take a look at [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers), which allow you to run JavaScript operations in a background thread.  However, they are not widely implemented yet (read: not available in Internet Explorer).

Comment: You're right. With a simple timeout I was able to draw the gif but not continue animating. What I am doing now is really hard to split up because I am working in an .hta and doing large file movement with ActiveX - there is one operation that is taking up 95% of the time. Really ugly, I know.

Comment: @fluorescentLAMP: then WebWorkers can't help you.  If you're using a HTA, you could consider a modeless dialog to offload the work onto.  HTAs can open modeless dialogs with no chrome (window frame) by setting the *unadorned* option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536761(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Clever! Couldn't this essentially be used to create multiple javascript threads, and using the parent object, talk to the original thread?

Comment: @fluorescent: technically, yes.  Unfortunately, it wouldn't be very memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Perform your heavy processing in a delayed function with [window.setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
function nameOfFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";
    window.setTimeout(lotsOfProcessing, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's strange indeed. Seems like `lotsOfProcessing` gets javascript's single thread before the dom has time to refresh, but it's the first time I hear of something like that.

You might try this (not that is not an ideal solution):

```
function nameOfFuntion()
    {
        document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";
        setTimeout(lotsOfProcessing, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this was my first attempt after I posted the question. However, it is providing me with an equally strange problem. The gif shows up, but only animates for the length of the delay. Perhaps I should post a separate question on this one.

Comment: You don't get any redraws when your JavaScript is running. That includes animated GIFs. If you want background calculations, you would need to look at WebWorkers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am limited to IE (and therefore no WebWorkers) since I am using an .hta .

Answer (score 0):

This is a vaguely educated guess but it may be worth trying to put `document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";` into a function eg.

```
function nameOfFuntion()
{
    showGif();
    //alert("test");
    lotsOfProcessing();
}

function showGif() {
    document.getElementById("gif").style.display = "inline";
}
```

My thinking is that perhaps the `lotsOfProcessing()` is getting *hoisted* to the top of `nameOfFunction()` because it's a function and therefore getting processed first.