# Getting animated graphics (a spinner) to load in order on non-Firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, browser, spinner

I have a web page I'm making where one particular feature works as designed in Firefox, but not in Chrome, Edge or Opera. It is an html spinner located on a certain popup-esque div whose characteristics are defined in CSS as thus:

```
#popupspinner {
    display: none;
    border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 8px solid gray;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

At a certain point I'm trying to show this spinner, then wait for some other javascript (Ajax) functions to process, then turn the spinner off. My javascript is something like this:

```
function dostuff()
{
     popupspinner.style.display = "block";

     doingmorestuff1();
     doingmorestuff2();
     doingmorestuff3();

     popupspinner.style.display = "none";
}
```

The problem is, in Firefox the spinner works as advertised. When the user clicks on a button to invoke the dostuff() function, the spinner shows, then the other functions run, then the spinner goes away.

In every other browser, however, the spinner does not start until **after** the doingmorestuffX() functions are done. It took me a while to do so, but eventually I figured that out when I commented out the popupspinner.style.display = "none" line. The spinner did show, it just didn't start up until after the other functions were called.

In other words, in these other browsers it runs as if the code is like this:

```
function dostuff()
{
     doingmorestuff1();
     doingmorestuff2();
     doingmorestuff3();

     popupspinner.style.display = "block";
     popupspinner.style.display = "none";
}
```

Since these two lines of code are right after each other and only milliseconds apart, in effect the spinner never shows up at all.

I don't know, but I'm guessing this is something these other browsers do to run faster (???)

My question is, is there any way to force these other browsers to run the code in the correct order?

EDIT: Here is the full code section:

```
function getPropertyInfo()
{
    popupspinner.style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function() {
        getCoords();
        getBasicInfo();
        getAscendLegal();
        getOwners();
        getValues();
        getPhotos();
        getElectedOfficials();

        popupspinner.style.display = "none";

        document.getElementById("tab1").className = "nav-link active";
        document.getElementById("tab2").className = "nav-link";
        document.getElementById("tab3").className = "nav-link";
        document.getElementById("tab4").className = "nav-link";
        document.getElementById("tab5").className = "nav-link";
        basicvalueinfo.style.display = "block";
        ownership.style.display = "none";
        photos.style.display = "none";
        requests.style.display = "none";
        electedofficials.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("container-all").style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOM style change waiting for pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124674/dom-style-change-waiting-for-pause)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question might be a duplicate of [DOM style change waiting for pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124674/dom-style-change-waiting-for-pause)

The problem is that your `doingmorestuffX` functions are blocking browser's main thread - so there are no resources left to refresh the page with new styles applied.

The easiest solution would be to run the code after a timeout, so the browser has some time to rerender the style changes. Look at the corrected example below:

```
function dostuff()
{
     popupspinner.style.display = "block";

     setTimeout(function() {
          doingmorestuff1();
          doingmorestuff2();
          doingmorestuff3();

          popupspinner.style.display = "none";
     });
}
```

With the code above the browser:

- applies `block` styling to `popupspinner` element,
- queues function to be run after a timeout,
- renders the page with styling changes applied (spinner becomes visible),
- runs the function from timeout queue,
- applies `none` styling,
- renders the page (spinner disappears).

Comment: Thanks, that (mostly) worked. I had to move the end of the setTimeout function below some other stuff I had after the popupspinner.style.display = "none" line to get it to work properly. It works in Chrome, sort-of works in Edge  (the spinner doesn't spin, however), still works in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Opera. I'm wondering if Opera's ad blocker has something to do with that??

Comment: Welcome! Yup, if you're doing some more things afterwards you probably would like to move everything to the setTimeout - to avoid main thread blocking.

Comment: @JohnA Can you please mark my answer as the correct?

Comment: @JohnA The opera issue is weird - I'm working on the Opera and everything works as expected. It's shouldn't be the issue from adblocker I guess. Can you post some failing example?

Comment: Here is a link to a test version of the project I'm working on: https://jcgis.jacksongov.org/test/parcelviewer/johntest/WebMap1.aspx

Comment: Click "I agree" on the splash screen. Then zoom in really close to a random area until you start seeing parcels show up. Click on a random parcel. A popup pops up. Click on the blue button that says "Click for property information." There is supposed to be a spinner that spins beneath the address. Having tested it out some more, it always works in Firefox, most of the time works in Chrome (albeit sometimes with a delay), sometimes works in Edge, and in Opera works maybe 1/4 of the time. All very inconsistent. Full code section in question will be just below:

Comment: I added the full code section to the end of my original post at the top.

Comment: As far as I see the loader shows always when I start with cleared cache (browser has a time to rerender the page when is waiting for some XHR responses). I would suggest to cut your long-running tasks into pieces using setTimeouts or async/awaits.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that wouldn't really be practical. I was actually trying to *combine* some of those function calls a little while ago to save work on our database server. I suppose this'll have to do.